# Universal word for bakkie

Tags: single-word-requests

I live in South Africa where we call a two or four seater cabbed vehicle with a bin a *bakkie*. A truck which takes large loads is not a *bakkie*. *Bakkies* are always around the size of a car. However *bakkie* is a colloquial term.

I was looking for an international or universally recognised term for this.

Truck:

> noun
>
> 1.
>   a large, heavy road vehicle used for carrying goods, materials, or troops; a lorry.
>
> synonyms:  lorry, articulated lorry, heavy goods vehicle, juggernaut;

Lorry:

> noun BRITISH
>
> a large, heavy motor vehicle for transporting goods or troops; a truck.
>   "a lorry driver"
>
> synonyms:  truck; juggernaut

Neither of the above are right and a juggernaut is not correct either.

So what is the correct term?

Comment: You probably won't find a universally-acceptable answer. A bakkie could be an SUV (U.S.), a ute (Australia), a twin-cab (four-seater, U.K.) or any other national/regional variant. I think @JOSH is probably closest with Pickup but that may well not be recognized in other countries. EDIT: Sorry, I somehow missed the fact that Hugo had also submitted "Pickup".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think pick-up truck is the term used in other countries:

***[Bakkie](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bakkie):***

[image](truckandute.wordpress.com)

> - a small vehicle with an open part at the back in which goods can be carried

***[Pickup truck](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pickup-truck)***:

> - a small vehicle with an open part at the back in which goods can be carried

(Cambridge Dictionary)

***[As a side note](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/bakkie),***  the term bakkie derives from dialectal Dutch bakkie:

> - Borrowing from Afrikaans bakkie, from dialectal Dutch bakkie, ***from bak ‎(“a tough/cool car”, slang)***  + -ie ‎(“-y, -ey”, diminutive suffix).

(Wiktionary)

Answer (score 3):

Trucks, lorries and juggernauts are much larger than bakkies.

[Oxford Dictionaries Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bakkie) define *bakkie* as a ***light truck*** or ***pickup truck***.

So you can use one of those two terms.